# SoftKeyboardStateListener not working on Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

This is the way I use to listen for soft keyboard visibility changing:

```
    final SoftKeyboardStateWatcher softKeyboardStateWatcher
            = new SoftKeyboardStateWatcher(mainLayout);
    softKeyboardStateWatcher.addSoftKeyboardStateListener(new SoftKeyboardStateWatcher.SoftKeyboardStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSoftKeyboardOpened(int keyboardHeightInPx) {
            bottomToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSoftKeyboardClosed() {
            bottomToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

My app is made for SDK >= 16 and works perfect for all pre-Lollipop devices and I tested it on HTC One M7 with 5.0.2 Android and results were ok. But, when I tried to test it with Nexus 4, API 22 and Nexus 5, API 23, `onSoftKeyboardOpened` and `onSoftKeyboardClosed` are never get called.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you a solution or cause for this problem ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

I hope this may help you.. :)

Comment: No, this doesn't help. This code only shows keyboard. I have a problem with "catching" the moment when keyboard is shown and when is hidden.